# How to calculate the likelyhood that a single measurement "belongs" to a standard distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, sensitivity-specificity

(Apologies in advance for using wrong terms and probably asking the wrong question)

Given a standard distribution with some $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and a single measurement $m$. Can I calculate the likelihood that $m$ "belongs" to the given standard distribution?

---

For context: I'm working on a real-time monitoring solution. We measure a count at a regular interval. The measured counts follow a normal distribution, which give me my $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Now given an alerting threshold, I want to calculate the specificity (for false positives) and sensitivity (for false negatives). Calculating the specificity is straightforward using the CDF. I'm struggling with calculating the sensitivity though. If I can calculate the likelihood that a measurement "belongs" to the normal distribution, then I can calculate the sensitivity. But I don't know how to do this, hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to calculate how many standard deviations ($\sigma$) your observation ($m$) is away from the mean ($\mu$) and then apply [z-score relations](http://www.z-table.com/) to find the probability of the observation.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? I'm using the z-scores for the specificity, as it tells me what % of samples I can expect to fall outside of the threshold given normal operations. But I don't know how to use z-scores to calculate the sensitivity.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean exactly by sensitivity?

Comment: Sensitivity is the "true negative" rate, i.e. the inverse of "false negatives". E.g. if it's 90%, then it tells me that 90% of the actual incidents will be detected, but 10% won't be.